# Sharepoint REST api returns Bad Request (400)

Tags: javascript, rest, typescript, sharepoint, odata

I am trying to create a **ListItem** using the **Sharepoint REST Api** (we just started with the Sharepoint Api so definitly no expert).
According to the **Microsoft [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292552.aspx)** the post should look like this: 
[image]

**I implemented the following code**

```
public addItemToList_Test(): void {

var listTitle: string = "DemoHomeWork";
var listItemType: string = "SP.Data." + listTitle + "ListItem";
var listItemTitle: string = "TestItem";
var postBody = { '__metadata': { 'type': listItemType }, 'Title': 'TestItem' };

var $: jQuery = require("jquery");
var call = $.ajax({
  url: listsUrl + "/GetByTitle('" + listTitle + "')/items",
  method: "POST",
  body: postBody,
  headers: {
    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    length: JSON.stringify(postBody).length
  }
});

return call;
}
```

However, this keeps returning me **Bad Request (400)** and figuring out why this happens is tricky to find out. Is there anyone who can tell me what is wrong with the request?

Answer (score 1):

How are you authenticating your request?

As given in documentation you need to pass `access_token` with your request to make API work. As in you headers, i am not seeing `access_token` being passed.

You need to first get `access_token` and then pass it with the request to make API work.

Also in

```
"'__metadata': { 'type': listItemType }" **listItemType** you are creating it manually but it can be different. Can you check getting it manually (`https://site_url/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(listtitle)`)
```

and check if `ListItemEntityTypeFullName` for this list is same as you have created `listItemType`.